# PHP Trying to get property of non-object for valid object

Tags: php, json, stdclass, notice

I have the following problem:
I'm iterating through an array of valid objects using foreach. When trying to access the resulting objects or their properties I am getting the notice I would be trying to access a non-object.

Here is the code:

```
$schema = json_decode($_POST['d']);
foreach ($schema->node as $node) {
    var_dump($node);
    if ($node->status == 1) {
        $data = $node->id;
    }
}
```

var_dump outputs the following:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (6) {
  ["status"]=>
  int(0)
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["title"]=>
  string(6) "Sensor"
  ["script"]=>
  string(24) "from eZness import swag;"
  ["x"]=>
  int(60)
  ["y"]=>
  int(80)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
$schema = json_decode($_POST['d']);
foreach ($schema->node as $node) {
    var_dump($node);
    echo $node->status; //Funnily this works
    $status = $node->status; //while this doesn't
    if ($node->status == 1) { //and this doesn't as well
        $data = $node->id;
    }
}
```

But when removing the var_dump even the echo doesn't work anymore.

**UPDATE:**
Resolved. Had a look at the client part of the application, there was a problem with pushing NULL values in the $schema->node array which of course are non-objects.

Comment: @MinaAbadir is right, you're missing the 'data' property in your php'ed JSON object. Otherwise, you're not adding the right data object you are referring to...

Comment: but `$node` was dumped correctly after that, so `$schema` should be fine. Probably, this code subset is fine.

Comment: 1) Please show us your full error message which you get 2) Does your code only loop 1 iteration? Or do you have more objects and you are looking at the wrong one 3) Also if you do `var_dump();` please take the output from the source code and post it here

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `$node->data`, which does not exist.

Comment: It does exist, it is part of the incoming JSON String.

Comment: It's not printed in the var_dump.

Comment: That would produce an "undefined property" notice, not a "non-object" notice.

Comment: I'm really sorry, my example code didn't fit the given var_dump. Now it does.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more of a workaround than an answer but: use

```
$schema = json_decode($_POST['d'],true);
```

[When you pass true as the second parameter, you get back an associative array instead of an object.](http://php.net/json_decode)

You should be able to loop through it with this:

```
 $schema = json_decode($_POST['d'],true);
foreach ($schema['node'] as $node) {
    if ($node['status'] == 1) {
        $data = $node['id'];
    }
}
```